# Using a custom jQuery function in an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I found this jQuery plugin which makes dropdownlists searchable (http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/). It's something I'd really like to use in my project, but I am experiencing a few problems. This is how I make the DropDownList, I also give it an id so I can apply the function to the dropdownlist:

```
<div id="geadresseerde-politici">
            @Html.Label("Politicus")
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PoliticianId, (SelectList)ViewBag.PolIds, new{@id = "polDrop"})
</div>
```

I also include the .min.js file in my `<head>` section like so:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.searchabledropdown-1.0.8.min.js")"></script>`

And my javascript part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#polDrop").searchable();
});
```

When I try to use my page the dropdownlist is not searchable and I get an error in the Chrome console saying: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'searchable'`

Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong. Do I need to include more files? I checked in the sources tab of Chrome (in the ctr+shift+i helper) and the .min.js script gets loaded. Do I need to 'tellt my code somehow that the searchable() function is in that extra js file and not in the standard js library?

Comment: Are you sure your HTML is definitely pulling in the searchable script? Add an alert to the top of the searchable plugin to check.

Comment: Do you mean that I should place an alert in the .min.js file my page is using?

Comment: Yes, at the top of jquery.searchabledropdown-1.0.8.min.js

Comment: Hmm weird! The alert actually shows, this probably means that this extra .min.js is not compatible with the general jQuery library I am using?

Comment: did you include the css? just for sure

Comment: I didn't include a specific css but I just checked the files I downloaded and it does contain a css and several other js files like shCore.js and such. Do I need to include all these files? I thought the .min.js and .src.js would be enough?

Comment: I generally use this plugin, have a look at it.Its good with many other functionality http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: I'll try it out, but could you tell me how to properly include this in my project and use in my .cshtml?

Answer (score 0):

```
The Way You Were Trying = 1 way
Second Way
Asp.net
Push Array In Asp.net ViewData['MYDATALIST'] As serialized data.

Jquery/js
my list = $('MYDATALIST').val();
Now Push This Array List In Your Select.
```

Comment: You Need To Provide Fiddle Or jsbin Example For More Practical Explanation

Comment: Does this have something to do with the jQuery library for a searchable dropdown list?

Answer (score 0):

Also add these files.Seems like they are also needed.Also change the location as yours

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="sh/shCore.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="sh/shThemeDefault.css"/>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="sh/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sh/shBrushJScript.js"></script>
```